# Why won't Android recognize my micro SD card and how can I get it to?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I have an Acer Iconia A1-810 that is running stock Android 4.4.2 and I have a SanDisk Ultra PLUS A1 16 GB microSD card. I am having so much trouble getting the tablet to recognize the card. If I have an SD card that is filled completely with zeroes, then Android should still be able to detect it and have some option to format it, right?

I have tried these things:

1. Totally wiping the MBR: I slide it into the micro SD slot, it makes the clicking noise for the locking mechanism, and the message I see up in the notification bar is "Removed SD card" (I just inserted it!!!). Going to *Settings > Storage*, under `SD CARD`, there is only one item and it is grayed out. The grayed out item says in big letters "Mount SD card" and the smaller text beneath it says "Insert an SD card for mounting". There is no option to format the card.
2. The micro SD cards's only non-zero bytes are 0x55 and 0xAA at offsets, meaning it has a valid MBR (albeit with no partitions set):  I slide it into the micro SD slot, it makes the clicking noise for the locking mechanism, and this time the message says "Damaged SD card". I pull down the notification panel and see that the smaller text below "Damaged SD card" says "SD card is damaged. Try reformatting it.". I click the notification item. Now in *Settings > Storage*, there a re four things': a blank bar that would normally show the card's data is divided up into, used space (it says it's calculating), total space (calculating), and finally an item for unmounting the card. Once it is "unmounted", the mount item is white/pressable. I press, but each time the mounting option will fail and the button will go back to being pressable and saying "Mount SD card". Once I leave settings, however, and come back to it,the option looks as it does in #1.
3. MBR has one unformatted partition set to type 0x0B (FAT32): See #1.
4. MBR has one partition entry set to 0x0B AND the partition has been formatted with `mkfs.vfat`: See#1.

What's going on?

Update: Formatting the whole SD card with FAT32 (no MBR) makes the device recognize it, but when I reboot it goes back to the above happening.

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui What makes you think an application is going to be able to see it if the operating system doesn't?